# How to activate a TextField and Duplicate Movie Clips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to ask, 
1 How to give focus to a TextField in AS3. in AS2 usually I'm using

```
Selection.setFocus("<name of textfield instance>");
fscommand("activateTextField");
```

2.How to duplicate movieclips in AS3. in AS2 I'm using

```
 <name of movie clip>.duplicateMovieClip();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate questions, both of which are answered online:

1. Use [`stage.focus`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#focus) to set the focus on any display object:

   ```
   stage.focus = name_of_textfield;
   ```
2. There's no direct equivalent to `duplicateMovieClip`, but you can do [approximately the same thing](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/display/duplicateDisplayObject.as) by creating a `new` instance from the original display object class and copying over properties from the original:

   ```
   function duplicateDisplayObject(target:DisplayObject):DisplayObject {
       var targetClass:Class = Object(target).constructor;
       var duplicate:DisplayObject = new targetClass() as DisplayObject;

       // duplicate properties
       duplicate.transform = target.transform;
       duplicate.filters = target.filters;
       duplicate.cacheAsBitmap = target.cacheAsBitmap;
       duplicate.opaqueBackground = target.opaqueBackground;
       if (target.scale9Grid)
           duplicate.scale9Grid = target.scale9Grid;
       if (target.parent)
           target.parent.addChild(duplicate);
       if (target.hasOwnProperty("graphics") && target["graphics"] is Graphics)
           Graphics(duplicate["graphics"]).copyFrom(Graphics(target["graphics"]));

       return duplicate;
   }

   duplicateDisplayObject(name_of_movieclip);
   ```